# Why does returning `&'static str` from an Axum handler show on a web page but `print!` or `format!` does not?

Tags: rust, rust-axum

While creating a simple web server using axum, I was able to flush the output on a route that leverages a function of return type `&'static str` but not with a function that just `print!`s the string.

```
use axum::routing::get;
use axum::Router;

#[tokio::main]
async fn main() {
    let app = Router::new()
        .route("/", get(root))
        .route("/avi", get(avi));

    axum::Server::bind(&"0.0.0.0:3000".parse().unwrap())
        .serve(app.into_make_service())
        .await
        .unwrap();
}

async fn root() -> &'static str {
    "Functional call is root"
}

async fn avi() {
    print!("Functional call is avi")
}
```

When visiting `localhost:3000/avi`, nothing gets printed on the screen. However, when visiting `localhost:3000`, the corresponding output `Functional call is root` gets printed.

Comment: `print!` writes to stdout - why would you expect that to end up being printed?

Comment: Why does returning an `&'static str` flushes to the web page but not `print!`? Sorry, I cannot understand the former more so, than the latter.

Comment: this is how `axum` works. if you return sth (that implements `IntoResponse`) from the handler it will be returned as a response to the request. `print!` doesn't return anything so nothing is shown.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The value you *return* from your Axum handlers determine what is sent back to the client. In the case of returning `&str` (as your `root()` handler does), it will return a successful response with that string as the content. In the case of returning `()` (as your `avi()` handler does), it will return a successful response but with no content.

The output of `print!` does not factor in because it is never directed to a source other than stdout. If you run your program in a local terminal, you'd see `"Functional call is avi"` in the terminal.